# Difference between iterating over a file-like and calling readline

Tags: python, io, iterator, subprocess, pipe

I always thought iterating over a file-like in Python would be equivalent to calling its `readline` method in a loop, but today I found a situation where that is not true. Specifically, I have a `Popen`'d process `p` where

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != "\n",
                         p.stdout))
```

hangs (presumably because `p` waits for input; both `stdin` and `stdout` are pipes to my Python process), while the following works:

```
list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != "\n",
                         iter(p.stdout.readline, "")))
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: Side note: instead of `fiter()` you can use `iter(f.readline, None)`, or even `iter(f.readline, "\n")` to replace `takewhile()`.

Comment: The issue you are seeing is related to buffering:  `file.__iter__()` does somehow more aggressive buffering than `file.readline()` – that's also why you can't mix them.  Too lazy to research the details and turn this into an answer at the moment…

Comment: @SvenMarnach: you mean `iter(f.readline, "")`, but yes, thanks, I keep forgetting about that :)

Comment: I used `None` to simulate `while True`.

Comment: Glad to see that you are human after all and doesn't know everything :-)

Comment: Ok. Actually, `None` would have worked too because I only read when I've just sent data to be processed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is purely in the implementation of iteration versus the `readline` method. File iteration reads in blocks (of 8 kilobytes, by default) and then splits up the buffer into lines as you consume them. The `readline` method, on the other hand, takes care never to read more than one line, and that means reading character by character. Reading in blocks is much more efficient, but it means you can't mix other operations on the file between reads. The expectation is that when you are iterating over the file, your intent is to read all lines sequentially and you will not be doing other operations on it. The `readline` method can't make that assumption.

As Sven Marnach hinted in his comment to your question, you can use `iter(f.readline, '')` to get an iterator that reads lines from the file *without* reading in blocks, at the cost of performance.

Comment: Do you know where in the CPython source code I can find the implementation of file iterators?

Comment: In `Objects/fileobject.c`. File objects are their own iterators, so there's no separate type. `file.readline` is `file_readline`, and iteration is done through `file_iternext`.

Comment: Direct link to source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/fileobject.c