# I tried to read some values in a txt file with java and python. Finally I could not manage it with both. I cannot figure out where is the problem

Tags: python, java, file, txt

I try to extract two kind of value from a txt file and write them to two separate txt files. I know that my functions work properly and I cannot figure out any mistake in my code. I realised that both two languages do not read the text file as it is. What I mean by that is for example normally the txt file has 10367 lines in it but when I count the lines in the code, there are 20735 lines in python. I cannot understand why this happens. I do not have an in-depth knowledge about how programming languages read the files. Please give me some information about the possible causes of this situation.

thanks in advance...

This is the pyhton code:

```
def main():
    serverSpeedsList=list()
    totalSpeedsList=list()

    ssString=str()
    stString=str()

    with open("C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\SpeedTests\\Logs\\log100.txt",'r') as inFile:
        for line in inFile:
            i+=1
            ss=speedOfServer(line)
            st=speedOfTotal(line)
            if ss!="":
                ssString+=ss+"\n"
                serverSpeedsList.append(ss)
            if st!="":
                stString+=st+"\n"
                totalSpeedsList.append(st)


    with open("C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\SpeedTests\\Results\\server100.txt",'w') as outFile:
        outFile.write(ssString)

    with open("C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\SpeedTests\\Results\\total100.txt",'w') as outFile:
        outFile.write(ssString)    

def speedOfServer(text):
    startStr="time\":\""
    endStr=" ms"
    result=str()
    startIx=text.find(startStr)
    endIx=text.find(endStr)
    if startIx>=0 and endIx>=0:
        result=text[startIx+len(startStr) : endIx]
    return result

def speedOfTotal(text):
    startStr="showProfile.php ("
    endStr="ms"
    result=str()
    startIx=text.find(startStr)
    endIx=text.find(endStr)
    if startIx>=0 and endIx>=0:
        result=text[startIx+len(startStr) : endIx]
    return result    

main()
```

and this is the java code to do the same

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {
   
    private static String serverSpeedFileName="C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\JavaSpeedAnalyser\\Results\\Server\\serverSpeed100.txt";
    private static String responseSpeedFileName="C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\JavaSpeedAnalyser\\Results\\Total\\responseSpeed100.txt";
    private static String logFilePath="C:\\Users\\yusuf\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\JavaSpeedAnalyser\\Logs\\log100.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StringBuilder serverSpeeds=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder responseSpeeds=new StringBuilder();
        try{
            File file = new File(logFilePath);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                String serverSpeed=speedOfServer(line);

                if(!serverSpeed.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(serverSpeed);
                    serverSpeeds.append(serverSpeed+"\n");
                }
                String responseSpeed=speedOfResponses(line);
                if(!responseSpeed.isEmpty()){
                    responseSpeeds.append(responseSpeed+"\n");
                }
            }
            br.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        writeToFile(serverSpeedFileName, serverSpeeds.toString());
        writeToFile(responseSpeedFileName, responseSpeeds.toString());


    }
    
    private static String speedOfServer(String text){
        String start="time\":\"";
        String end=" ms";
        String result="";
        int startIndex=text.indexOf(start);
        int endIndex=text.indexOf(end);
        if(startIndex>=0 && endIndex>=0 ){
            result=text.substring(startIndex+start.length(),endIndex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String speedOfResponses(String text){
        String start="%5bF%5dshowProfile.php (";
        String end="ms)";
        String result="";
        int startIndex=text.indexOf(start);
        int endIndex=text.indexOf(end);
        if(startIndex>=0 && endIndex>=0){
            result=text.substring(startIndex+start.length(),endIndex);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I try to analyse a logcat file from an android phone, this is why I try to do that but I cannot manage it. Please help me

Comment: I didn't even know you can iterate over *file*. You should probably do `for line in inFile.readlines():` instead of blatantly iterating the file itself. Apparently you're not getting the lines in.

Comment: hm, it seems I'm wrong, you can and should iterate over file if you just need to read lines. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10012710/1421036

Comment: what is the file contents?

Comment: you're not writing `stString` anywhere, instead you write `ssString` to both files